# Maximum deviation from numbers in a list

Tags: python

How do i make a function to find the average  and the max deviation( the highest # between average and another number from list)?

If the list was [1,6,8], it should print that the max deviation is 4 and the average is 5.

I should then write another function using these two values as the arguments to output them.

What is wrong with my code? I know i should use .sort for the max deviation but I'm not sure exactly how.

Assume I already outputted mylist in a previous function: def list_output(mylist)

```
def code(avg,max_dev):
    avg = sum(mylist)/len(mylist)
    max_dev = ????????
    return avg
    return max_dev

def main_output(avg,max_dev):
    print "The average is", avg, "The maximum deviation is", max_dev
main_output(code(avg, max_dev))
```

Comment: You can't put two `return` statements on a function. If you want to return more than one value, use a tuple.

Comment: @l19 the proper term for that in Python is a `tuple`.

Comment: @squiguy 1 is 4 off from 5.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
a = [1,6,8]
avg = sum(a, 0.0) / len(a)
max_dev = max(abs(el - avg) for el in a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers to your question loop three times over the entire list. Once to compute the average, and once each to get the max and min of the list. You can achieve the same with a single loop:

```
def avg_max_dev(num_list):
    total = 0
    minimum = maximum = num_list[0]
    for n in num_list:
        total += n
        if n < minimum:
            minimum = n
        elif n > maximum:
            maximum = n
    avg = total / len(num_list)  # float(total) on Python2
    max_dev = max(avg - minimum, maximum - avg)
    return avg, max_dev
```

**Edit:** @Slater Tyranus correctly criticizes that there is no performance gain from using a handwritten loop instead of the fast and readily implemented functions `sum`, `min` and `max`.

I tested the performance of our two function in IPython on Python3.3, dropping the float casting in Slater Tyranus' `calculate` function.

```
In [25]: from random import randrange

In [26]: nums = [randrange(200) for _ in range(10**6)]

In [27]: %timeit avg_max_dev(nums)
10 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit calculate(nums)
10 loops, best of 3: 77.5 ms per loop

In [50]: # Edit: @Jon Clement's solution

In [51]: def jon_clements(num_list):
    avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
    max_dev = max(abs(el - avg) for el in num_list)
    return avg, max_dev
   ....: 

In [52]: %timeit jon_clements(nums)
1 loops, best of 3: 250 ms per loop
```

Comment: They made else if for a reason.

Comment: Also worth noting that between your updating and the additional branch logic the performance boost in your more verbose solution is extremely minimal if not non-existent. That is to say, the difference in performance is small enough that the difference between runs is much larger than any actual performance difference between the two.

Comment: @simon you can avoid the `float(total) # on Python2` and just set `total = 0.0` to start with...

Comment: @simon thanks for the time it... but how come it got just one loop? (and isn't using `sum(num_list, 0.0)`...)

Comment: @JonClements: Those timings were done on Python3.3, so I figured adding 0.0 wouldn't help. I just retried your original function on Python2.7 and got 210 ms for the same list of numbers. The timeit magic function chooses the number of loops depending on the execution time of the loop and there seems to some threshold arount 200 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this for finding the max deviation, since you know that it will be either the difference between the smallest number and the mean, or the largest number and the mean.

```
max_dev = max([max(num_list)-avg, avg-min(num_list)])
```

That said, there are still issues with your code.

Keep in mind that in the inputs to your function are different from your outputs, so the first definition line:

```
def code(avg,max_dev):
```

should really be more like:

```
def code(num_list):
```

Because you want to calculate things based on num_list.

Also the line where you calculate average is very vulnerable to float division problems, so instead of saying:

```
avg = sum(mylist)/len(mylist)
```

I would instead add a float cast:

```
avg = float(sum(num_list))/len(num_list)
```

Additionally you can only have one return statement within a function, so you need to return both of your values together if you want to do that, like so:

```
return (avg, max_dev)
```

So in total I would rewrite your function as follows:

```
def calculate(num_list):
    avg = float(sum(num_list))/len(num_list)
    max_dev = max([max(num_list)-avg, avg-min(num_list)])
    return avg, max_dev

def main_output(avg, max_dev):
    print "The average is: ", avg, " and the maximum deviation is: ", max_dev
```

Comment: The float conversion to compute the average is only necessary in Python2. Python3 has true division by default.

Comment: if i use those two codes, my entire code only prints out the list. it doesn't calculate nor print out the avg or max_dev.

Comment: @simon True, but Python2 is still far more ubiquitous.

Comment: @lunapt I'm guessing you're calling it wrong. I guarantee it works. Try posting how exactly you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

The max dev would be the larger of the difference between the average and minimum value and the maximum value. You could do something like this...

`max_dev = max((avg - min(mylist), max(my_list) - avg)`

Global variables are generally not a good idea, therefore I would recommend passing my_list as a parameter to your funciton.

in order to return 2 values from a function you should create a tuple of the 2 and return both. Like this...

```
def code(my_list):
    #code goes here
    my_avg = ...
    my_max_dev = ...
    return (my_avg, my_max_dev)
```

and you can call your code like this...

```
avg, max_dev = code(my_list)
```

You should also have some logic to ensure that your list contains only numbers or you may end up with unexpected results!